# Fechar um Iframe de dentro de 2 Iframes ASPX

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

Estou precisando de ajuda para recarregar um iframe de dentro de 2 iframes , ja tentei parent.document, response.redirect, mas não ocorre o que solicito.

Se eu uso response.redirect(url), o Iframe1 é recarregado dentro do Iframe 3.

Se eu tento usar parent.document.getelementbyid ('iframe1') ou parent.document.getelementbyid ('iframe3') ou parent.document.getelementbyid ('<%=iframe1.ClientID.ClientID %>') ou parent.document.getelementbyid ('<%=iframe3.ClientID.ClientID %>'), é retornado nulo.

Anexei uma imagem sobre o que estou tentando fazer.

Eu quero que quando clicar o botao dentro do iframe3, que o iframe1 seja recarregado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou acessar dois níveis de "parent"? Contando a partir do frame atual aberto?

Comment: iframe de dentro de 2 iframes! como é isso? iframe 3 dentro de iframe 2 que está dentro do iframe 1 ?

Comment: sim, devido a plataforma ser antiga, essa foi a forma mais rapida para resolver o problema.

Comment: Dessa forma quando iframe 1 for recarregado iframe 2 e iframe 3 também serão recarregados, portanto basta colocar o botão no iframe 1. Mas se desejar fazer isso de dentro do iframe 3 veja a resposta que postei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refresh(){
//pode referenciar qual frame, 0 1 2 ....
top.frames[0].location.reload();
}
//-->
</script>

<button onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: haha Fiz dessa forma e recarregou a pagina toda, não apenas o iframe1.

Comment: Não tem como vc NÃO RECARREGAR os iframes contidos no iframe 1 se este iframe 1 for recarregado pois os outros são conteúdo do iframe 1

Comment: Leo, nao tem problema recarregar os iframes dentro do iframe1. A questão é que dessa forma recarrega a pagina toda e não apenas o iframe 1 e os iframes dentro dele, assim removendo as abas abertas dentro da plataforma.

Comment: Fiz com top.frames[2].location.reload(); e deu certo também, obrigado Leo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma parent.location='url', dessa forma recarregou apenas o iframe 1. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.